# MATLAB: Starting with a vector of starting points and a vector of end points, make runs of consecutive numbers between these points

Tags: matlab, vector

This is probably simple but here is my problem.

I have two vectors, starts and ends. Starts are the starting points of sequences of consecutive numbers and ends are the end points of sequences of consecutive numbers. I would like to create a vector which contains these runs.

So for example, say

```
starts = [2 7 10 18 24]  
ends = [5 8 15 20 30]
```

I would like to create the following vector

```
ans = [2 3 4 5 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 19 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]
```

Using starts:end only uses the first element of each vector

---

I would also like to do this without using a (for) loop in order to keep it as fast as possible!

Thanks for reading

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's always the same number of start and end points, and they always match (e.g. the nth start corresponds to the nth end), then you can do

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(s,e) (s:e), starts, ends, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

For a bit more detailed explanation, the `arrayfun(@(s,e) (s:e), starts, ends, 'UniformOutput', false)` part will generate a sequence of n cell arrays, where n is the length of the `starts` and `ends` vectors, such that each cell array has the sequence `starts(i):ends(i)` corresponding to the ith elements of the two vectors. Then the `cell2mat` function will fuse each of the individual cell arrays into 1 larger matrix.

Comment: But is it actually faster than a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, it seems like this is lots faster, at least for the problem size shown.

Comment: +1: By the way, you can use `@colon` instead of declaring an anonymous function wrapper `@(s, e)(s:e)`.

Comment: @EitanT very cool, I didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

When you're worried about making it fast, preallocate:

```
starts = [2 7 10 18 24]  
ends = [5 8 15 20 30]
a = zeros(1,sum(ends)+numel(ends)-sum(starts));
% or a = zeros(1,sum(ends+1-starts))
j = 1;
for i = 1:numel(ends)
    j2 = j+ends(i)-starts(i);
    a(j:j2) = (starts(i):ends(i));
    j = j2+1;
end
```